# How to custom the number of labels the ion.rangeslider shows?

Tags: slider, rangeslider

I am using the ion.rangeslider ([here](http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/en.html)) and sometimes the container is not big enough to show labels for all values.

I would like to customize the way labels are shown. Something like every 2 steps (or 10 or 100, etc).

Comment: The answer for this can be found on this github discussion [#275](https://github.com/IonDen/ion.rangeSlider/issues/275).